# Add an image to content builder via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, content-builder

I want to add an image to content builder via api and retrieve the image published Url. I suspect I need to use the assets/v1/content/asset but will I be using POST OR GET command ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, correct. You need to make a POST call to the /asset/v1/content/assets endpoint with the details of the Image. Below is a sample payload:

```
{
    "name": "API To Insert Image 3",
    "assetType": {
        "name": "png",
        "id": 28
    },
    "FileProperties": {
        "fileName": "APIImageInsert3.png"
    },
    "file": "..."
}
```

where the value for the file key is the Base64 string representation for the image.